# How do I parse iso8601-2004 datetimes into datetime following current iso8601 standard

Tags: c#, datetime, iso8601

I am currently making request to an API which include the 24:00 as a valid datetime.
Meaning a possible response from a get request might be `2022-11-21T24:00:00.000Z`

Which I cannot parse into a System.Datetime, as it follows the Iso8601 standard which currently don't support this timestamp, but did so in version 2004.

The json response is deserialized using system.text.json deserializers
How do I properly handle this case?
in a simple manner

**For those stating it is a duplicate,** please consider that the day/month/year also have to be changed when going from `2022-11-21T24:00:00.000Z` -> `2022-11-22T00:00:00.000Z` when adding an hour like this, which the current dupplicate doesn't seem to cover.

In general **this has was allowed** using the iso8601-2004 version, but removed in the current version.
https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:8601:-1:ed-1:v1:en

So what do i do to handle this in between persiod?

Comment: What are you using to deserialize? Can you post a bit of code, a Minimum Reproducible Sample?

Comment: @daniherrera info added

Comment: IMHO that is not a valid time. What that represents really?

Comment: @CetinBasoz: It's valid as an ISO-8601 representation of midnight at the end of the day. See section 4.2.3 of ISO-8601.

Comment: @JonSkeet the old one states its valid, its not valid anymore according to the documentation I have found. 
which sort of gives me an issue with handling this.

Comment: @IamnotFat: The link you've provided simply doesn't include the whole standard - in particular, section 4.2.3 is still present, but not included on that page. Have you actually purchased the 2019 edition? Where is the evidence that it's been removed in the 2019 edition?

Comment: I would say the only thing that's different between the other question and this one is that the other one stated that they couldn't use Noda Time, which *does* allow parsing 24:00, although it basically silently adds a day (so you can't roundtrip the value).

Comment: Then I guess the foreword is quite different to the actual content.

Comment: There is though multiple github issues that states that 24 is not supported. 
but either way, I ended up parsing to to nodatimes, and then back to datetimes.

Comment: @JonSkeet, yes I see it there. That is unfortunate. At least good they also didn't do that for minutes and seconds.

Comment: @CetinBasoz: It's sort of unfortunate, but also not. It can be *very* useful to have the ability to refer to "the end of a day" without going for 23:59:59.999999999 for example. It's just really hard to represent in libraries :(

Comment: @JonSkeet, I can't see a relation to 23:59:59.9999999999. I don't understand what does that mean "going for 23:59:59.99999999". So if you extend it to other parts, you should have 23:60:00. What about if you extent it to milli, micro, nano ... how would you ever have it there? It has no usefulness really. At the end of day, it is the start of the next day which simply is 00:00:00.00000000...
It is unfortunate. I wouldn't say ISO makers were right at all.

Comment: " It has no usefulness really." It really, really does. If you want to express that a shop closes at midnight, for example, it's useful to be able to say that the closing time is 24:00:00. It allows you to express exclusive upper bounds, basically - and that's where the relationship with 23:59:59.999 (etc) comes in, which would have to be a precision-specific upper bound. Just because *you've* never seen any use for this doesn't mean it "has no usefulness".

Comment: @JonSkeet, it is said as closing time is 00:00:00. It has a date component too which is next day. On one hand you say exclusive and on the other say 23:59:59.999. That value is not a precise value and in datetime ranges upper bound is exclusive to be precise. You don't say between 2022/1/1 00:00:00 and 2022/1/1 23:59:59.999 but >= 2022/1/1 00:00:00 and < 2022/1/2 00:00:00. That is precise. Can you really show me one real world usage code wise? How 2022/1/1 24:00:00 (imaginary) would be different from 2022/1/2 00:00:00? Why then we don't have 25:00:00 to say the closing time is next day at 1 AM

Comment: "On one hand you say exclusive and on the other say 23:59:59.999"- yes, I'm saying *that's an ugly workaround due to not being able to use a genuine exclusive upper bound of 24:00*. Being able to express a value which is "just" beyond the range of actual values is useful for expressing exclusive upper bounds. I've seen enough examples of this in the decade of maintaining Noda Time (while unfortunately still not having a good representation in the library) that I'm confident that there are reasonable use cases. I suspect I won't be able to persuade you of that though, so I won't argue further.